# Could not find org.jetbrain.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.1

Tags: flutter, firebase, kotlin, gradle

I am doing a flutter project and currently trying to connect the project to firebase database. However I got some issue regarding the kotlin version.

This is my error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNKza.png)

This is my code for the build.gradle in the android file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.1'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrain.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my code for the build.gradle in the android/app file

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.clinicconnect_test"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.clinicconnect_test"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation "org.jetbrain.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I have tried multiple solution from various sources but unable to resolve the issue. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It's `org.jetbrains.kotlin` not `org.jetbrain.kotlin`.

(They say two brains are better than one.)